# Nesting DO While LOOP rotation angle shear theory on epsilon L

Tags: vba

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2OCk.png

Like from the image, i want to looping epsilon L with an iteration, while my iteration only use epsilonL (assumption) + 0.00001 until epsilonL(assumption) same as the epsilonL (function)

```
Dim b As Long, c As Long, d As Long, e as long
epsilon d = -0.0002
epsilonr = 0.01
epsilonL(assumption) = 0.0001
Do
b = 2e5* epsilonL(assumption)
c = 2e5 * (5e-2 + epsilonL(assumption)
epsilonL(real) = epsilonr + (5e-5 * (3.44* 0.012 * b - 0.003 * c)
E = epsilonL(assumption)
epsilonL(assumption)= epsilonL(assumption)+ 0.00001
Loop While Abs(E - epsilonL(real)) > 0.00001
```

This iteration really BAD, only work with epsilon d -0.0002. then another iteration must be choose which I don't know...
Can you choose better iteration guys??

You guys who has experience enough at nesting do loop, please help I'm just a Civil Engineer, this is my pre post graduate class which I must assign in 26 June. Big thanksss if you want to help

Comment: Long is an integer value.  You might try changing you long's to double (double precision floating point values)

Comment: You should also provide the whole function and the function for epsilon (if that's the case).  Also put 'Option explicit' at the top of your module as this will help you identify errors in your code.